# Email de confirmação

Tags: php, email

Boa tarde, eu recentemente inplementei um sistema de confirmação de email para os usuarios que forem se cadastrar e esta funcionando perfeitamente, porem quero que os usuarios ja cadastrados confirmem tbm mas quando tentei usar o msm sistema não obtive sucesso... alg pode dar uma olhada?

```
<?php    
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email2 = $_POST['email'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "teste";

    //Criar a conexao
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

    $result_leados = "INSERT INTO leados (email) VALUES ('$email')";
    $resultado_leados = mysqli_query($conn, $result_leados);

    $leado_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $valor_chave = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i'));

    $link = "http://localhost/Mail/baixar.php?chave=".$valor_chave;

    $result_links_emaos = "INSERT INTO links_emaos (link, leado_id) VALUES ('$valor_chave', '$leado_id')";
    $resultado_links_emaos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_links_emaos);
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o exatamente seria "confirmar os usuários já cadastrados"?

Comment: queria que eles confirmem que esse email realmente existe, enviando um email de confirmação para o email cadastrado

Comment: E em que momento esse e-mail deverá ser enviado? Ao usuário acessar o sistema? Ou será enviado para todos automaticamente? Como você diferencia os usuários que já verificaram o e-mail? Aliás, o código que postou não parece enviar e-mail algum; o que seria esse código?